# Non-Invertible Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there such a result as this in linear algebra? If $A$ is any 2x2 matrix which is not invertible then there is a 2x1 matrix $B$ such that $AB=0$?

Comment: if you are looking for B that is not the null vector Thats basically the definition of not invertible

Comment: Yes - this is saying a non-invertible matrix has a determinant of $0$ and so an eigenvalue of $0$ with an associated non-zero eigenvector

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is an $n$x$n$ matrix that is not invertible,i.e. has determinant=0, there is a non-trivial, i.e. not entirely 0, $n$x1 matrix $B$ such that $AB=0$

Comment: And if you want an $n \times n$ matrix $B$, just repeat the column from this solution $n$ times.